# Counting how many "countdown" sequences exists in array

Tags: pseudocode

I know this sounds kind of simple but I'm trying to get the count of "countdown" sequences that exists in my array. Example:
[1,2,3,2,5,4,3,0] - > 2 *([3,2] and [5,4,3])*
I just need a little push, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate through the list every time the countdown breaks you increment the counter

Python, also known as pseudo code:

```
def count_finder(l):
    prev = l[0]
    counter = 0
    inCount = False

    for num in l[1:]:
        if num == prev-1:    #Checks if the previous was 1 greater than this one
            inCount = True   #       if it is then "inCount" is True

        elif num+1 != prev and inCount:  #Checks if your exiting a countdown
            inCount = False              
            counter += 1   #Increment Counter
        prev = num         #Change previous number to current number for next loop
        
    if inCount: counter+=1  #If the loop ends while in a count down increment counter
    return counter
    
print(count_finder([9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]))
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you. I wrote my own code at the end, i'll compare it with your answer. Thank you for taking the time to write that! :)

Comment: No problem,  Let me know if you didn't understand part of the python syntax :)